# How much overhead does Apache Cordova add to an app?

Tags: html, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

If I build an hybrid app with Apache Cordova, how much overhead will be added to my app? I mean, how many MB will be added to my app package?

I'm concerned about the final size of my app

Comment: Compile it and look how much MB are added

Comment: This is a very poor question. There are lot of things which effect app size. You may use plugin which will increase the app size, you may not use the plugin, then app will be smaller. You may use template which has it's own size. Thus it can't be said like this. And for a simple idea you can just build a sample 'hello world' project and see the apk size.

Comment: I cannot compile and verity myself, can someone that actually develops with it help me?

Comment: I'm not interested in an absolute number, but an order of magnitude. Are we speaking of 100 KB? 1 MB? 5 MB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you include in your project. In `cordova` you have plugins which will increase the size of the output, also you have some `ui` frameworks such as `ionic` or `jquery-mobile` or `onsen-ui` they will increase the file size too; java scripts, images, ... also will affect on your output size.

But the size of a simple `Hello World` application without any additional library in `cordova` is about 2Mb (which is greater than building native app with java)

Comment: Why would images and javascripts add additional overhead in a Cordova app? Is an image used in a Cordova app bigger than the same image used in a web app? This is a really confusing answer to a straightforward question.

Comment: @ThoraciusAppotite your images will be boundled in the cordova app, so if you have s simple helloworld and another helloworld including 10 images, the output size is different, unless you are setting urls to another website and not loading them locally